# ALTER ROLE

Tags: sql-server

При записи команды
    ALTER ROLE MyRole ADD MEMEBER MyUser
подчеркивает ADD и пишет, что ожидалось "WITH". ADD MEMBER вообще не признает. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А у вас версия какая? Внимательнее читайте документацию - данная конструкция поддерживается начиная с SQL 2012:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189775%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Для 2008 используется команда sp_addrolemember.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что у меня 2012. И на обоих компьютерах та же проблема.

Comment: А уровень совместимости для базы какой выставлен? если 100 (2008), то тоже не взлетит, скорее всего.

Comment: понял, принял. Использовал addrolemember, спасибо!